# Find $\int \frac{x^2}{2x-1}\mathrm{d}x$

Tags: calculus, integration

Use the substitution $2x-1$ to find $\int  \frac{x^2}{2x-1}\mathrm{d}x.$

I started out by using the substitution to find $\mathrm{d}x$ in terms of $\mathrm{d}u$.

$$
\frac {\mathrm{d}u}{\mathrm{d}x} = 2 
$$
$$
\mathrm{d}x = \frac {1}{2}\mathrm{d}u
$$

Now the question looks like this:

$$
\int \! \frac{x^2}{u} \, \cdot \frac {1}{2}\mathrm{d}u
$$

I then found $x^2$ in terms of $u$:

$$
2x-1 = u
$$
$$
x = \frac {u+1}{2}
$$
$$
x^2 = \left(\frac {u+1}{2}\right)^2
$$

I then substituted this back into the equation.

$$
\int \! \frac {(\frac {u+1}{2})^2}{u} \cdot \frac {1}{2}\, \mathrm{d}u
$$

$$
\int \! \frac {(\frac {u+1}{2})^2}{2u}\, \mathrm{d}u
$$

From here I have tried expanding out the brackets, and using a substitution to put $2u$ on the top of the fraction, but neither method got the correct answer, and I have spent a long time on the question. Am I on the right track here, or should I be approaching this any differently? Thanks

Comment: You should get $\frac{1}{8}\int(u+2+\frac{1}{u})du$ if you multiply out and simplify. (Using long division instead of substitution is another method that will work on this problem.)

Answer (score 3):

$$\int\, \frac {\left(\dfrac {u+1}{2}\right)^2}{2u}\, \mathrm{d}u =\int\frac{u^2 + 2u + 1}{8u} = \frac 18 \int\left(u + 2 +\frac 1u\right)\,du $$ $$=  \frac 18 \left(\int u\,du + 2\int du + \int \frac 1u\,du\right)$$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Yep, got it now, thanks very much!

Comment: You're welcome, Ed.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

Here it is another way to solve it: consider the following algebraic manipulation

\begin{align*}
\frac{x^{2}}{2x-1} & = \frac{1}{4}\times\frac{4x^{2}}{2x-1} = \frac{1}{4}\times\frac{(4x^{2}-1) + 1}{2x-1} = \frac{1}{4}\times\left[\frac{4x^{2}-1}{2x-1} + \frac{1}{2x-1}\right]\\\\
& = \frac{1}{4}\times\left[2x+1 + \frac{1}{2x-1}\right]
\end{align*}

Can you take it from here?